# How do I create a nested cookiecutter?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I have a peculiar use case for a nested cookiecutter structure. My aim is to have:

- an "outer" template that can be cut straight from GitHub;
- an "inner" template that can be cut locally to generate templated subfolders inside the outer template.

It's a different use case from the [multiple "parallel" cookiecutters case](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/advanced/directories.html) detailed in the docs.

This is an example of the folder structure I'm trying:

```
cookiecutter-for-analysis
├── cookiecutter.json
└── {{cookiecutter.repo_name}}
    ├── README.md
    ├── .gitignore
    └── project_template
        ├── cookiecutter.json
        └── {{cookiecutter.analysis_name}}
            ├── README.md
            ├── pyproject.toml
            ├── .gitignore
            ├── notebooks
            └── sql
```

Within the outer cookiecutter.json I define (among other things) `repo_name`, so that when I run

```
cookiecutter cookiecutter-for-analysis
```

a folder called `repo_name` is created with the outer template.

Within the inner cookiecutter.json I define (among other things) `analysis_name`. I would then like to run

```
cd repo_name
cookiecutter project_template
```

so that a folder called `repo_name/analysis_name` is created with inner template.

The issue I'm running into is that on the outer cookiecutter creation it's failing to find the inner cookiecutter attribute `analysis_name`:

```
Error message: 'collections.OrderedDict object' has no attribute 'analysis_name'.
```

Is there any way I can achieve this nested cookiecutter functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out, and it was very simple. The "copy without render" flag in cookiecutter.json (see [docs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/advanced/copy_without_render.html)) allows me to avoid rendering the inner template:

```
...
"_copy_without_render": ["project_template"]
...
```